# notepad++ to word: keeping style

Tags: notepad++

I open some code (.m file for Matlab) in notepad++ and it is displayed in a nice style.

How do I copy and paste it into word and keep the style?

Comment: You mean the syntax coloring?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Plugins</kbd> → <kbd>NppExport</kbd> → <kbd>Export to RTF</kbd>.